# Shipping Problems - AUS

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I'm having huge problems with shipping on Magento 1.9.1

I've tried using Table Rates & the Extension by webshopapps, both giving me grief and defaulting to the * * Postcode range $606 (I just put this figure to test) as shown below;

```
Country Region/State    City    Zip/Postal Code From    Zip/Postal Code To  Order Subtotal From Order Subtotal To   Shipping Price  Delivery Type

AUS                         0   9999999 606 Delivery
AUS *   NSW 1100    1299    0   9999999 35  Delivery
AUS *   NSW 2000    2234    0   9999999 35  Delivery
AUS *   NSW 2235    2999    0   9999999 50  Delivery
AUS *   VIC 3000    3207    0   9999999 35  Delivery
AUS *   VIC 3208    3999    0   9999999 50  Delivery
AUS *   QLD 4000    4199    0   9999999 60  Delivery
AUS *   QLD 4208    4287    0   9999999 70  Delivery
AUS *   QLD 4288    4299    0   9999999 110 Delivery
AUS *   QLD 4300    4305    0   9999999 60  Delivery
AUS *   QLD 4306    4499    0   9999999 110 Delivery
AUS *   QLD 4500    4519    0   9999999 60  Delivery
AUS *   QLD 4520    4999    0   9999999 110 Delivery
AUS *   SA  5000    5199    0   9999999 35  Delivery
AUS *   SA  5200    5999    0   9999999 60  Delivery
AUS *   WA  6000    6199    0   9999999 60  Delivery
AUS *   WA  6200    6797    0   9999999 150 Delivery
AUS *   TAS 7000    7999    0   9999999 60  Delivery
AUS *   NT  800     899     0   9999999 130 Delivery
AUS *   QLD 9000    9015    0   9999999 60  Delivery
```

This is a sample .csv I downloaded and then edited and uploaded, is there something here I'm doing wrong?

If I use the default Australia Post within Magento, it does not split the packages into different boxes for delivery. I ship Computers/Computer parts so alot of customers cannot order more then 2 items as it exceeds the maximum weight range of Australia Posts 22KG. If I set the weight of the items to 0 this allows my customers to order more then two/three items but costs me money as the shipping is not calculating correctly.

EDIT: This issue still has not been resolved. If anyone has any extra information that would be great.

Comment: Do you want to calculate a shipping rate as per weight or item quantity ?

Comment: Is it possible to do both? I bulk ship Computer System and some are quite heavy.

Comment: If not possible then Item Quantity would be preferable.

Comment: have you tried webshopapps matrixrate? as per your question you are not able to get a correct shiping rate when you use above data it shows the default rates i.e. **606**  if you want to apply rate according to weight then you have to use **Weight vs. Destination** and for item need to use **# of Items vs. Destination** your order details not meeting the conditions you mentioned in the csv thats why it shows you default rates. try the other two option or check the data which you are inserting at the time of order.

Comment: two things with same shipping method for a single store is not possible. you have to use two method for this or else need to make customization in the extension.

Comment: If I change to # of items vs Destination it still defaults to $606.00 instead of the actual post code and state I am inputting (VIC - 3178).

Here is the download link incase you want to view my .csv file. http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08501945351573951173

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39607/discussion-between-ashish-madankar-and-suranyi).

Comment: This issue still has not been resolved with Ashish, if anyone has any extra information that would be great.

Comment: Have u tried the csv which i send you.

Comment: Yes I've tried (you can check yourself with the URL I gave you) using Vic + 3178 for Post Code, still defaults to $666.00. Using # of items vs Destination.

Comment: please come to chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your csv data in the question you have entered a values in city column so due to this you will get a rate only if you will enter a city name as it is which you mentioned in the csv for ex **VIC** which is not possible practically customer may make mistakes in it as it is text box while entering a address details. You may either enter a space or make case changes while order due to which it is unable to calculate a rate properly.

Solution to this is either you have to make a city as a drop down due to which above mistakes can be removed or **remove city value from csv**.

Then you will get a rate on following condition no need of city.

```
Country 

Region/State 

Zip/Postal Code From

Zip/Postal Code To  

# of Items From 

# of Items To   

Shipping Price  

Delivery Type
```

Comment: Thankyou, Asish was very helpful.